# fusion 2 tables with inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite

in my database i have 2 tables.
table1
i have `ID` and `NAMES`

table2
i have `ID`, `IDASSOCIATION`, `QUANTITY`

so
i have 2 names in table1:
john and tom

and in table2 i have 3 lignes
john, 1
tom, 1
john, 1

nombre one is the quantity

in my result i want get

john = 2
and tom = 1

so i do this:

sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.IDASSOCIATION, (SELECT SUM(t2.id_qte) FROM associationdepotarticle t2 WHERE t1.fusiontable = t2.fusiontable GROUP BY t2.IDASSOCIATION) as id_qte FROM articletable t1, associationdepotarticle t2";

but i not get this:

john = 2
tom = 1

why ? what i will do, i need correction please

Answer (score 0):

You can just `join` the tables together and use `sum`:

```
select t1.name, sum(t2.quantity)
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.idassociation
group by t1.name
```

It's not completely clear from your sample data what to join on, but I assume it's the `idassociation` field.  If you want to return those names in `table1` which aren't in `table2`, then use an `outer join`.

Comment: thanks for reply but i get a error
this is my sql with your code:
                sql = "SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.id_qte) FROM articletable t1 INNER JOIN associationdepotarticle t2 on t1.fusiontable = t2.fusiontable GROUP BY t1.designation";

i get a error that id_qte dost exist :/

idassociation is just a exemple i have "fusiontable"

Comment: @thedarkside -- difficult to say, can you create a sqlfiddle.com with an example?  I'm sorry, but I'm not exactly sure with the `fusiontable`...